# Extracting CRS Codes from PyProj Library

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinate-systems, pyproj

I need help with a python program. I am looking to obtain crs codes/definitions from Pyrpoj library, add them to a list, allow the user to select a crs from the list and print it out, but it does not seem to work. I have made sure to update the library to the latest version. I will be grateful if you guys can help me out here.

Here is the code I tried.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyproj

def get_crs_list():
    # Get a list of available CRS codes from the pyproj CRS database
    crs_list = list(pyproj.database.get_codes("CRS"))
    return sorted(crs_list)

def print_selected_crs():
    selected_crs = combobox.get()
    print("Selected CRS:", selected_crs)

# Create the main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CRS Selector")

# Create a label and a drop-down list (Combobox) for selecting the CRS
label = ttk.Label(root, text="Select a CRS:")
label.pack(pady=10)

crs_list = get_crs_list()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=crs_list)
combobox.pack()

# Create a button to print the selected CRS
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Print CRS", command=print_selected_crs)
button.pack(pady=10)

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Error message:-

```
line 7, in get_crs_list
    crs_list = pyproj.get_crs_list()
AttributeError: module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'get_crs_list'
```

### Found a solution that worked for me.

```
def get_crs_list(): 
    crs_info_list = pyproj.database.query_crs_info(auth_name=None, pj_types=None) 
    crs_list = ["EPSG:" + info[1] for info in crs_info_list] 
    print(crs_list) 
    return sorted(crs_list) 

Output: ['EPSG:2000', 'EPSG:2001', 'EPSG:2002', 'EPSG:2003', 'EPSG:2004',.......]
```

Comment: What's the version of pyproj you are using?

Comment: pip install pyproj --no-binary pyproj
Requirement already satisfied: pyproj in c:\users\fujitsu\pycharmprojects\seismic\venv\lib\site-packages (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\fujitsu\pycharmprojects\seismic\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyproj) (2023.5.7)

Comment: Your posted code uses `crs_list = get_crs_list()`, but in the error message it is `crs_list = pyproj.get_crs_list()`.  Your posted code should not get such error.

Comment: Hey. Sorry about that I think I pasted the error message from another solution I tried. I managed to find a solution for my issue. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) in the comments, your error message looks different from the code you tried. However, if I run the same code you posted, I get the following error -

```
TypeError: get_codes() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

Following the official [documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/database.html#pyproj.database.get_codes), the function *"pyproj.database.get_codes()"* requires atleast 2 arguments. These are *"auth_name"* and *"pj_type"*

You can get the list of acceptable values for *"auth_name"* using -

```
pyproj.get_authorities()
```

The output that I get from above is -

```
['EPSG', 'ESRI', 'IAU_2015', 'IGNF', 'NKG', 'OGC', 'PROJ']
```

Now, for *"pj_type"* you have mentioned to use *"CRS"*, therefore, a fix for your problem would be -

```
def get_crs_list():
    # Get a list of available CRS codes from the pyproj CRS database

    # SOLUTION
    crs_list = list(pyproj.database.get_codes(auth_name="all", pj_type="CRS"))
    return sorted(crs_list)
```

#### After referring to the documentation, the modified final solution -

```
def get_crs_list(): 
    crs_info_list = pyproj.database.query_crs_info(auth_name=None, pj_types=None) 
    crs_list = ["EPSG:" + info[1] for info in crs_info_list] 
    print(crs_list) 
    return sorted(crs_list) 

Output: ['EPSG:2000', 'EPSG:2001', 'EPSG:2002', 'EPSG:2003', 'EPSG:2004',.......]
```

Thanks [@Hanzo Hasashi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22025977/hanzo-hasashi) for updating!

Comment: Thanks for the assist.

crs_list = list(pyproj.database.get_codes(auth_name="all", pj_type="CRS"))
    print(crs_list)
    return sorted(crs_list)

I ran this to check the list, but the output shows an empty list,
but the program does work correctly.

Output: 
[]

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hi again. Looking at the documentation again, I ran this code and the output is what I needed.

def get_crs_list():
    crs_info_list = pyproj.database.query_crs_info(auth_name=None, pj_types=None)
    crs_list = ["EPSG:" + info[1] for info in crs_info_list]
    print(crs_list)
    return sorted(crs_list)

Output: 
['EPSG:2000', 'EPSG:2001', 'EPSG:2002', 'EPSG:2003', 'EPSG:2004',.......]

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!